# @stripe/react-stripe-js - How to properly type paymentType on createPaymentMethod with Typescript

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments, typescript-typings

I'm trying to properly type an input parameter to stripe's `createPaymentMethod` method, defaulting the value to "card", like this

```js
  const createStripePaymentMethod = async (paymentType: string = "card", cardElement: StripeCardElement) => {
    ... do some things

      let response = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: paymentType,
        card: cardElement,
      });
```

I  have `paymentType` typed as a string but doing so gives me a type error:

```
Type 'String' is not assignable to type '"card" | "alipay" | "au_becs_debit" | "bancontact" | "eps" | "giropay" | "ideal" | "p24" | "fpx" | "sepa_debit" | "sofort"'.
  Type 'String' is not assignable to type '"sofort"'.ts(2322)
payment-intents.d.ts(38, 5): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'CreatePaymentMethodData'
```

The compiler seems to indicate that the correct type is `CreatePaymentMethodData` but if I substitue `string` for `CreatePaymentMethodData` I get another error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CreatePaymentMethodData'.ts(2322)
```

Looking at payment-intents.d.ts, I doubt this is actually what I need to be using as a type; the original typeerror seems to indicate that there's an enum that I need to be referencing but I can find that nowhere - how do I type this properly?
Any help would be much appreciated.

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "types": ["googlemaps", "jest"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using TypeScript and the following code works for me.

```
const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);
    if (!cardElement) {
      return;
    }

interface IPaymentMethod {
      error?: StripeError | undefined;
      paymentMethod?: PaymentMethod | undefined;
}

    const {
      error,
      paymentMethod,
    }: IPaymentMethod = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: cardElement,
    });
```

Also, if you hover over the createPaymentMethod it should show you this.

```
(method) Stripe.createPaymentMethod(paymentMethodData: CreatePaymentMethodData): Promise<{
    paymentMethod?: PaymentMethod | undefined;
    error?: StripeError | undefined;
}>
```

And when I hover over type and card I can see that it inferred the types.

type: `CreatePaymentMethodCardData.type: "card"` 
card: `const cardElement: StripeCardElement`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to type the `paymentMethod` parameter, as typing it as a string gives me errors.  I don't actually see any typings in your example

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if that works.

Comment: im trying to dynamically type the payment method type. so instead of type: `card`, do type: paymentMethod and you will see the errors I'm getting.  I do see the error message that references CreatePaymentMethodData, however, using that as a type just freaks out the compiler even more.

Comment: Can you add your tsconfig to your question so I can use your rules.

Comment: You created a CardElement and I don't understand why you would not pass "card" into createPaymentMethod because that is a **value not an interface**. So, if it is a card element why do you want it to accept the other payment types? Again, I will help you once you add your tsconfig to the question.

Comment: added to original question

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing in your code but I used your tsconfig and I have no errors the type extends the type of Payment Method. I even put more strict rules in my config. Again, you are passing an interface where a value goes and you are using a card element therefore the value is a card.